# dll doesn't seem to be registered

Tags: windows, dll, dllregistration

I built a dll in Visual Studio.  I then register the dll on a machine with Windows Server 2008 R2.  I use the following command:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe /unregister .\My.Program.dll
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe /codebase .\My.Program.dll
```

I get the message:

un-registered successfully

then:

registered successfully

So it looks like the dll is registered and unregistered successfully, but when I run the program that uses the dll. The dll doesn't behave how I expect it to behave.  It seems to ignore changes I made in the dll and just behaves as the former dll before changes were made to it.  What can I do to make sure my new dll is registering?

Comment: Check to see what modules are loaded in the process to see if the correct DLL has loaded from the correct path (e.g. by using a debugger or by using Process Explorer)

Comment: Process Explorer is great! Wow! Cool!  Process Explorer shows the wrong dll loaded.  How can I get my dll to load?

Comment: I restarted the services and then called on the process again.  This time it looks like the correct dll has been loaded.  I verified it with Process Explorer as well.  That fixes my problem!!  Thank you very much for your help!!